# Sliders episode that makes fun of the Lewinsky Controversy

Tags: episode-identification, sliders

This episode shows the president of an alternate America hugging main character Maggie on TV similarly to [the infamous footage of Bill Clinton hugging Monica Lewinsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinton%E2%80%93Lewinsky_scandal) - turns out this president's staff encourages such shenanigans because the public focuses on *them*, and ignores the more serious things he does, such as planning to unleash chemical weapons on Switzerland.

Comment: Nu'Daq, did Valorum get the answer correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is  [*Sliders: A Current Affair*](https://earthprime.com/episode-guide/a-current-affair).

Maggie inadvertently becomes romantically linked to the President and it distracts the press from his shenanigans in Switzerland.

[image]